# Command to list and install Ubuntu Security Updates

Tags: apt, updates, security, patch

Could you please suggest the commands in Ubuntu similar to below Centos YUM commands.

```
yum --security check-update ## To list security updates
yum --security update ## To install security updates
```

Thanks & Regards
Anoop

Comment: A stock install of Ubuntu is designed --out-of-the-box-- to check for, download, and install security updates automatically multiple times each day without any user interaction. So no similar feature is included in apt nor snapd. You must create your own workaround to this popular Ubuntu feature, as the duplicate questions shows.